# Can React Native detect what's the default SMS app set by user?

Tags: react-native, sms

is there any way I can detect what's the default SMS app set for a user's phone on React Native? Reason is because I was trying to initiate sms with `sms:` URI Schema, however this will fail when user had other 3rd party apps set as their default messaging app and it's causing a bad user experience :/

Comment: Are you using Expo? If so, have you tried the expo-sms library? https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sms/ I don't think it will detect the default app, but it might fail more gracefully.